# Adding score and current date to plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have to retain the score and current date for a game in a plist . I created a dictionary with two arrays:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dateArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    scoreArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    [self getDate];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"score" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    int lastItemIndex = scoreArray.count;
    [scoreArray insertObject:[dict objectForKey:@"scoreElements"] atIndex:lastItemIndex];
}

-(IBAction) saveData
{
    NSString *plistPath =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Score.plist"];
    NSMutableArray* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    [plistDict setValue:self.scoreLabel.text forKey:@"scoreElements"];
    [plistDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically: YES];
}
```

This code is good only for the last game played, but I want to fill the tableView with the old scores as well. How can I do it?

Comment: Why don't you use a storage system instead of plist file?

Comment: Add a data model with `NSCoder` support and use `NSKeyedArchiver` to save the data model in the Documents directory. Yo will be able to access the score, date and other items or interiors directly. As an added benefit debugging will be much easier.

Comment: Put an array in the plist to hold the data. Also note that you can't write your plist file in the app's bundle. That may work in the simulator but it won't work on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
[scoreArray insertObject:[dict objectForKey:@"scoreElements"] atIndex:lastItemIndex];
```

why don't you use

```
[scoreArray addObject: dict["scoreElements"];
```

Also when you are saving using below code, it will always set new value to "scoreElements" overriding old ones.... so you have to use array as well.

```
[plistDict setValue:self.scoreLabel.text forKey:@"scoreElements"];
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use NSUserDefaults to store stuff and retrieve it later on.
Check out the reference about this class at Apple :

[nsuserdefault apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html)

Comment: Don't use `NSUserDefaults`, it is not designed to be a data model.